# How do we prove the trigonometric identity $(1 - \cos x)\left(1 + \frac{1}{\cos x}\right) = \tan x\sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

Please show me the steps to completing this: $$(1-\cos x)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right) = \tan x\sin x$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(1-\cos x)(1+\frac{1}{\cos x})$

$=1+\frac{1}{\cos x}-\cos x-1$

$=\frac{1}{\cos x}-\cos x$

$=\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\cos x}$

$=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos x}$

$=\sin x\tan x$

Comment: Why is there cos^2x in the numerator of the (1-cos^2x)/cosx ?
Shouldn't it be (1-cosx)/cosx ?

Comment: $\cos x = \cos x \cdot \frac{\cos x}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos x}$

Answer (score 2):

$$(1-\cos x)(\frac{1+\cos x}{\cos x})=\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos x}=\frac{\sin x\cdot \sin x}{\cos x}= \tan x \cdot\sin x$$

That's all.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've accidentally typed a mistake in the equation. 
What I meant is this: (1-cosx)(1+(1/cosx)) = tanxsinx.

Comment: But, he proved this.

Comment: exactly thats what i have done

Comment: My bad, but I still dont understand why there is cos^2x

Comment: There's no difference. $1+\frac1{\cos x}=\frac{\cos x}{\cos x}+\frac1{\cos x}=\frac{\cos x+1}{\cos x}$
Plus, $(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)=1-\cos^2 x$

Comment: @KinsonChan $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$, so $(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)=1-\cos^2 x$.

Comment: @user236182 I understand the concept of a^2 - b^2 but that still doesn't help me understand how 1-cosx / cosx can become 1-cos^2x / cosx

Comment: @KinsonChan $(1-\cos x)\left(\frac{1+\cos x}{\cos x}\right)$ becomes $\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\cos x}$, _not_ $\frac{1-\cos x}{\cos x}$.

Comment: @KinsonChan $(1-\cos x)\left(\frac{1+\cos x}{\cos x}\right)=\frac{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}{\cos x}=\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\cos x}$.

Comment: @user236182 Yes I understand it now, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$(1-\cos x)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)$$
$$=(1-\cos x)\left(1+\sec x\right)$$
$$=1+\sec x-\cos x-1$$
$$=\frac{1}{\cos x}-\cos x$$
$$=\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\cos x}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos x}=\sin x\tan x$$

Comment: Can it be answered without the use of sec x ? I have not learnt that yet.

Comment: @KinsonChan $\sec x=1/\cos x$ by definition

Comment: yes, of course you can simply multiply $(1-\cos x)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)$

Comment: Oh. But can you explain to me why there is a cos^2x instead of cosx in the numerator?

Comment: @KinsonChan Let $a=\cos x$ then what is $\frac{1}{a}-a$?

Comment: as you take LCM of $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ & $\cos x$ so you multiply $\cos x\times \cos x$ to get $\cos^2 x$ in numerator